# Generic List, items counting with conditional-statement

Tags: c#, list, generics, count, conditional-statements

I have a Generic List. it has a ListfilesToProcess.Count property which returns total number of items, but I want to count certain number of items in list with conditional-statement.

I am doing it like this:

```
int c = 0;
foreach (FilesToProcessDataModels item in ListfilesToProcess)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked == true)
                    c++;
            }
```

Is there any shorter way like *int c = ListfilesToProcess.count(item => item.IsChecked == true);*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, use LINQ's `Count` method, with the [overload taking a predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx):

```
int count = ListFilesToProcess.Count(item => item.IsChecked);
```

In general, whenever you feel you want to get rid of a loop (or simplify it) - you should look at LINQ.

Comment: Your response helped me do the following: `foreach(var item in Model.listOfObjects(t => t.ObjType == "M")`. I'm using it in an `MVC View` where I'm displaying two separate HTML tables - one for male ( ObjType = "M") students and one for female (ObjType = "F")