# Generic list Foreach loop with conditional statement

Tags: c#, list, generics, foreach, conditional-statements

I am using foreach loop to get generic list items which iterates all items, but I want to get certain items, with a condition. 
I am doing it like following:

```
 foreach (FilesToProcessDataModels item in ListfilesToProcess)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked)
                {
                    //file operations
                }
            }
```

Is there any way that i can do it without if statement, to iterate the data where *item.IsChecked==true* in foreach loop.

Comment: What is wrong with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616553/generic-list-items-counting-with-conditional-statement ?

Comment: Did you look into LINQ before asking this question? As per my answer on your previous question: "In general, whenever you feel you want to get rid of a loop (or simplify it) - you should look at LINQ."

Comment: @I4V: That was just counting. This is doing other operations. But it looks like the OP hasn't done any research into LINQ since the last question :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq `Where`:

```
var checkedItems = ListfilesToProcess.Where(i => i.IsChecked);
foreach (FilesToProcessDataModels item in checkedItems)
{
    // file operations
}
```

Comment: Thanks. my last question was about counting and not related to this question. I used it like *foreach (FilesToProcessDataModels item in ListfilesToProcess.Where(item => item.IsChecked))* and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx%3a)

```
var foo = ListfilesToProcess.Where(i => i.IsChecked);
```

Comment: There's no indication that using `ToList` is appropriate here. The OP only wanted to execute an action for each element in the filtered sequence - just `Where` and a `foreach` loop is fine for that.